# Does usb port on yoga 11 e lenovo have audio in if so can u help me out

Tags: usb, laptop, audio, lenovo-laptop, amplification

I have a yoga 11 e lenovo and im wondering if my usb ports can carry audio in since im trying to plug my amp to my laptop and if so how exactly do u set it up?

Comment: Hmmm, going to need more info than that. USB can carry audio as well as any other kind of data. I'm assuming when you plug it in Windows (which I assume you're running) will pop up and ask you to install some drivers. What's the amp model?

Answer (score 0):

They can "carry audio" in the sense that you can plug in a USB audio device (sometimes called "external soundcard" or "USB soundcard"), which you then can connect to your amp.

They very likely cannot "carry audio" in the sense that you can just buy a passive adapter, and then route the internal sound hardware through any of those USB audio ports.

It's also possible that your amp already can act as a USB device, but as you didn't tell us anything about your amp, we cannot say.

Which USB soundcard you should use also depends on your amp, so we cannot give recommandations. Stereo USB soundcards start pretty cheap.